# Postgres heap vs SQL Server clustered index

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, clustered-index, database-internals, heap

I am transitioning from SQL Server to Postgres, and one of the biggest things for me to digest is the non-existence of the "clustered key" that sorts the data in Postgres.

Can someone share their thoughts on how Postgres avoided the need for an *internally* sorted dataset and how it works with large heap tables and still supply exceptional performance?

Comment: SQL Server tables can be used as heaps but the benefit of having the clusters index that automatically sorts data is far greater to not have one. 
Even though postgres does have clusters index it doesn't maintain the order of data. And this made wonder how it performs under a significant workload.

Comment: Did you benchmark your database to see if not having a clustered index really slows down things?

Comment: I have mostly worked with multitenant data sets with SQL server and having tenants data in a sorted manner has allowed the read-ahead-read  to be more effective and load more relevenet/validata data to the buffer cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try pg_repack extension to cluster online with less locking

Answer (score 6):

PostgreSQL simply doesn't implement this feature.  There is no trick to not implementing it.  It isn't implemented in the straight forward, uncomplicated way of just not doing it.  To use one bit of jargon, all btree indexes in PostgreSQL are "secondary indexes", not "primary indexes".  Even the primary key's index is a "secondary index".

There are some cases where clustered keys (or index organized tables, as another product calls them) are important, and in those cases PostgreSQL fails to "supply exceptional performance".  You can argue about how common those cases are, of course, but they certainly do exist and it is unfortunate that PostgreSQL doesn't offer a solution for them.  There have proposals to address this, but I don't think any of those efforts are currently active.

In some cases, you can ameliorate the problem by using the CLUSTER command, or by implementing partitioning, or by using covering indexes, but none of these is entirely satisfactory as an alternative to real clustering.

Comment: Hey @jjanes, thanks for your feedback. Using CLUSTERED is definitely a possibility. But that will require an explicit lock on the table which is a no-no mostly. And Yes I have taken declarative partitioning to keep the data sets more manageable. So from what you have mentioned getting the correct indexes is probably more critical.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL doesn't do anything special to replace the "need" of a clustered index.

It just simply doesn't have that feature. ([Some would say](https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2014-01/unreasonable-defaults-primary-key-clustering-key) that isn't a great loss.)

You can manually perform a one-time cluster with `CLUSTER` or pg_repack.

There is also declarative partitioning (though it has a number of caveats until PostgreSQL 11). It isn't quite clustering, but can be used to group rows into specified buckets.